# .mat file ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 219, 170 only in colab, available in vscode

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, loading

I'm trying to use a colab for GPU, and I found that loading .mat file does not working in colab, while it works fine in vscode.

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat = sio.loadmat('track.mat')
```

This is the code and it does not cause any error in vscode.
However, in colab,

[image]

This error comes up.

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Could it be that the file [has been corrupted](https://github.com/cornellius-gp/gpytorch/issues/1636)? Try to use a different file, does it produce the same error?